# joomla module position if else and

Tags: php, if-statement, joomla, joomla3.0

I am creating an responsive template and for that to happen I need to use and if else and function. This is what I have so far.

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('left')) { ?>
<p>Left + Content</p>
<?php } elseif ($this->countModules('right')) { ?>
<p>Right + Content</p>
<?php } elseif ($this->countModules('left')) && ($this->countModules('right')) { ?>
<p>Left + Right + Content</p>
<?php } else { ?>
<p>Content</p>
<?php } ?>
```

I am now receiving the error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND) in index.php on line 197

Line 197 =

```
<?php } elseif ($this->countModules('left')) && ($this->countModules('right')) { ?>
```

I have tried adding an extra () but that did not work:

```
<?php } elseif (($this->countModules('left')) && ($this->countModules('right'))) { ?>
```

I am forgetting something but what.

Comment: You are closing the `elseif` before `&&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is wrong and instead of adding the () you should remove a set. See the adapted code below.

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('left') && $this->countModules('right')) { ?>
<p>Left + Right + Content</p>
<?php } elseif ($this->countModules('right')) { ?>
<p>Right + Content</p>
<?php } elseif ($this->countModules('left')) { ?>
<p>Left + Content</p>
<?php } else { ?>
<p>Content</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Hopefully this puts you in the right lane.

Answer (score 0):

You have your brackets in the wrong place. Try replacing the following:

```
<?php } elseif ($this->countModules('left')) && ($this->countModules('right')) { ?>
```

with this:

```
<?php } elseif ($this->countModules('left') && $this->countModules('right')) { ?>
```

Comment: The order is also wrong because with the original order Joomla will keep saying Left + Content even when the right module position is also in use.

Comment: @ Lodder thank you for your answer. I have tried it but as HennySmafter is saying it keeps telling Left + content.